# Miracles performed by Krishna in Mahabharat

Tags: mahabharata

In Mahabharat, was Krishna regarded as a deity and incarnation of Vishnu from the very beginning, or was he deified in subsequent editions of the epic?

Did anyone ask Krishna to prove his divinity?

Did Krishna perform any miracles in Mahabharat?

Did Krishna perform any miracles in Mahabharat to prove his divinity?

Comment: What is your definition of a miracle? Krishna defeated very powerful demons. Not only that he used supernatural weapons in doing so. Also, he has shown to have several siddhis.

Comment: The link above does explain Krishna's powers.  However, if I compare Krishna to Jesus, Moses, and Mohammed, they had to perform miracles because their own people did not believe that they were God (in the case of Jesus) and they were sent by God (in the cases of Moses and Mohammed).  Is this because Krishna was so powerful that it was evident that he was God, and no one questioned him?